Expo build failed for android with error 127
I'm a new mobile developer using Expo to create my app. After installing Node.js and Expo on my computer, I implemented my app, which looks good when running on the emulator. To generate an APK file, I ran the commands "eas build:configure" and "eas build --platform android". However, the Expo server responded with a "Build failed" message. When I logged into the website, I encountered an error message. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. Please suggest to me.
This is my error that I got.

This is my dependecies.
 "dependencies": {
"@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
"expo": "~51.0.28",
"expo-font": "~12.0.9",
"expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
"expo-router": "~3.5.23",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
"expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.5",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
"react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
"expo-build-properties": "~0.12.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
"@types/react": "~18.2.45",
"jest": "^29.2.1",
"jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
"react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
"typescript": "~5.3.3"},

